# How can I work my JavaScript read more work

Tags: javascript

I found some script for read more / less text. The script works perfectly in my laptop, but when I upload it on the server it doesn't work. You can have a look here: [www.engliScare.net](http://www.engliScare.net) in the section of Lesson offers. it just shows there "read more" but shows the hidden text too. I wonder why, since it works fine on my laptop.
Here's the code:

js/hide.js

```
function evtEllipse(info) {
  info.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
}
function spanEllipse(info) {
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

and this is how it looks:

```html
<p>
  are held between the teacher and the student. All attention is given to the only student and the teacher gets to know the
  <span class="read_button" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip; read more</span>
  <span class="hide" onclick="spanEllipse(this)">
      student abilities 
  and disabilities and also his weaknesses and strengths in English. 
  </span>
</p>
```

of course I added the script like this:

```html
    <script src="js/hide.js"></script>
```

and this is CSS:

```css
    .hide {
  display: none;
}
.read_button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F56692;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none; 
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.read_button:hover{
  color: #2a2e35;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-grey-1);
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

As a snippet:

```js
function evtEllipse(info) {
  info.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
}

function spanEllipse(info) {
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.read_button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F56692;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.read_button:hover {
  color: #2a2e35;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-grey-1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>
  are held between the teacher and the student. All attention is given to the only student and the teacher gets to know the
  <span class="read_button" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip; read more</span>
  <span class="hide" onclick="spanEllipse(this)">
      student abilities 
  and disabilities and also his weaknesses and strengths in English. 
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: You should get used to looking at the dev tools/console errors. That file is showing a 404 missing file error, in other words it doesn't exist on the server or where you are referring to it.

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work" in more technical terms? What errors do you observe in the console or network tabs of your debugging tools?

Comment: You added the script but is it also being loaded? Check in your den tools to see if there is a 404 error.

Comment: I added a Stack Snippet, showing the code works in isolation, so the problem is definitely in how you are linking the JavaScript to the HTML. There are thousands of questions about how to debug that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `var(--color-secondary)` and `var(----color-grey-1)` are not defined

Answer (score 0):

YOu can also use that...

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('span.MoreLess')
  .forEach( sp => sp.onclick =_=> sp.classList.toggle('less') )
```

```css
span.MoreLess {
  cursor    : zoom-out;
  }
span.MoreLess.less  {
  font-size : 0;        /* hide span content */
  cursor    : zoom-in;
  }
span.MoreLess.less::after {
  font-size   : 1rem;
  content     : '\2026 read more';
  font-weight : bold;
  }
span.MoreLess.less:hover::after {
  font-size   : 1.1rem;
  }
```

```html
<p>
  are held between the teacher and the student. 
  All attention is given to the only student and the 
  teacher gets to know the
  <span class="MoreLess less" >
    student abilities and disabilities and also 
    his weaknesses and strengths in English.
  </span>
</p>
```